# How to load the data from development database before test?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, testing

I am new to rails. I write a performance test for a controller action which require load large amount of data from mysql.
  But when I run the test, the rails will delete all data from the test database. I know the rails will load data from fixtures, but I see the fixtures only contains the sample data line by line. It seems impossible to write all data in the fixtures.

How can I load data into the test database from development database?Or there is any way to avoid deleting data from test database before test?

Comment: did you try this `rake db:test:clone && rake db:seed RAILS_ENV='test'`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker) gem to generate random sample data for testing your application. Here's a good example on how to use it http://www.railscarma.com/blog/technical-articles/faker-gem-fake-data-generation-ruby/